# How to find a keyword in a visual studio project

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, visual-studio

I am looking at an old project one of my colleagues wrote in `AngularJS` in Visual Studio and as we all know, it's pretty difficult to understand code when you're not the one who wrote it. So I found some errors, but it's a pretty big project with 56 classes and interfaces.

The error that I got was

> Cannot find name 'saveSession'

So what I wanted to do was check in the whole project where I can find this `saveSession` method. But as I mentioned. It's a very big project and the one thing that could help me is something like a search bar or a `ctrl F` for the whole project because now i can only search keywords in the current file.

Is there a way to find keywords through the whole project?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

This shortcut searches the whole solution by default.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + shift+ F should work and help.
You just need to select look in entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> Find and replace -> Find in Files